# Path parameters optional in Swagger annotation

Tags: php, swagger, slim, swagger-php

I'm using this [library](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php). I want to have an optional parameters in my url

for instance I have this route

```
$app->get('/files/{order:\d+}[/{all:0|1|all}]', 'myctroller');
```

And my annotation is

```
/**
 * @SWG\Get(path="/doc/v1/files/{id_ordine}/{all}",
 *   tags={"GETFILE"},
 *   produces={"application/json"},
 *   @SWG\Parameter(
 *     name="order",
 *     in="path",
 *     type="integer",
 *     required=true,
 *     default="123",
 *   ),
 *   @SWG\Parameter(
 *     name="all",
 *     in="path",
 *     type="string",
 *     enum={"0","1","all"},
 *     default="all",
 *     required=false,
 *   ),
 *   @SWG\Response(response="200", description=xxx"),
 *   @SWG\Response(response="404", xxx")
 * )
 */
```

With Chrome and with [this plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/swagger-ui-console/ljlmonadebogfjabhkppkoohjkjclfai) I can do CURL with my documentation.
If I select all with 0 value my curl is like

```
http://localhost/doc/v1/files/123/{all}
```

I'd like to have a CURL like

```
http://localhost/doc/v1/files/123
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently there was a rewrite of swagger ui (with version `v3.0.0`), in that your code works as expected. 
So this is probably a bug in the version that the chrome extension uses `v2.2.8`.

As the swagger ui is only html and js, you can simply [download a recent version of the swagger-ui](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/releases) and use this one instead of the extension.